# SqlCeReplication Conflicts - Error 28634

Tags: sql, replication, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

Is there any connection between error **Failure to write to a message file** and **conflicts on Publication side** on SQL 2000 server?

Comment: I can't figure out the error from CE books online. It may be 29501 as well as 28563 or 28634. Can you provide error code and full message? And what is SQL CE version?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for 28634:
Failure writing to a message file on the device. The error typically comes from running out of memory. While there might appear to be plenty of available memory on the device, there might not be enough contiguous memory. Try closing other applications or warm booting the device.

So that should be fixed... I believe not related to conflicts,